# Eclipse and GWT Debug issues

Tags: java, eclipse, spring, gwt, eclipse-plugin

I am new to Java and GWT. I have been following the Google getting started tutorial for building the StockWatcher app (http://code.google.com/webtoolkit/gettingstarted.html) and have hit a roadblock. The project runs fine, but when I try to run it in debug mode I get a "Source not found" error:

```
// Compiled from URLClassPath.java (version 1.5 : 49.0, super bit)
public class sun.misc.URLClassPath {

  // Field descriptor #27 Ljava/lang/String;
  static final java.lang.String USER_AGENT_JAVA_VERSION = "UA-Java-Version";

  // Field descriptor #27 Ljava/lang/String;
  static final java.lang.String JAVA_VERSION;

  // Field descriptor #33 Z
  private static final boolean DEBUG;

  // Field descriptor #165 Ljava/util/ArrayList;
  private java.util.ArrayList path;

  // Field descriptor #167 Ljava/util/Stack;
  java.util.Stack urls;

  // Field descriptor #165 Ljava/util/ArrayList;
  java.util.ArrayList loaders;

  // Field descriptor #166 Ljava/util/HashMap;
  // Signature: Ljava/util/HashMap<Ljava/lang/String;Lsun/misc/URLClassPath$Loader;>;
  java.util.HashMap lmap;

  // Field descriptor #164 Ljava/net/URLStreamHandler;
  private java.net.URLStreamHandler jarHandler;

  // Method descriptor #198 ([Ljava/net/URL;Ljava/net/URLStreamHandlerFactory;)V
  // Stack: 3, Locals: 4
  public URLClassPath(java.net.URL[] arg0, java.net.URLStreamHandlerFactory arg1);
     0  aload_0 [this]
     1  invokespecial java.lang.Object() [278]
     4  aload_0 [this]
     5  new java.util.ArrayList [150]
     8  dup
     9  invokespecial java.util.ArrayList() [299]
    12  putfield sun.misc.URLClassPath.path : java.util.ArrayList [272]
    15  aload_0 [this]
    16  new java.util.Stack [152]
    19  dup
    20  invokespecial java.util.Stack() [307]
    23  putfield sun.misc.URLClassPath.urls : java.util.Stack [274]
    26  aload_0 [this]
    27  new java.util.ArrayList [150]
    30  dup
    31  invokespecial java.util.ArrayList() [299]
    34  putfield sun.misc.URLClassPath.loaders : java.util.ArrayList [271]
    37  aload_0 [this]
    38  new java.util.HashMap [151]
    41  dup
    42  invokespecial java.util.HashMap() [304]
    45  putfield sun.misc.URLClassPath.lmap : java.util.HashMap [273]
    48  iconst_0
    49  istore_3
    50  iload_3
    51  aload_1 [arg0]
    52  arraylength
    53  if_icmpge 73
    56  aload_0 [this]
    57  getfield sun.misc.URLClassPath.path : java.util.ArrayList [272]
    60  aload_1 [arg0]
    61  iload_3
    62  aaload
    63  invokevirtual java.util.ArrayList.add(java.lang.Object) : boolean [301]
    66  pop
    67  iinc 3 1
    70  goto 50
    73  aload_0 [this]
    74  aload_1 [arg0]
    75  invokespecial sun.misc.URLClassPath.push(java.net.URL[]) : void [317]
    78  aload_2 [arg1]
    79  ifnull 94
    82  aload_0 [this]
    83  aload_2 [arg1]
    84  ldc <String "jar"> [4]
    86  invokeinterface java.net.URLStreamHandlerFactory.createURLStreamHandler(java.lang.String) : java.net.URLStreamHandler [332] [nargs: 2]
    91  putfield sun.misc.URLClassPath.jarHandler : java.net.URLStreamHandler [270]
    94  return
      Line numbers:
        [pc: 0, line: 97]
        [pc: 4, line: 73]
        [pc: 15, line: 76]
        [pc: 26, line: 79]
        [pc: 37, line: 82]
        [pc: 48, line: 98]
        [pc: 56, line: 99]
        [pc: 67, line: 98]
        [pc: 73, line: 101]
        [pc: 78, line: 102]
        [pc: 82, line: 103]
        [pc: 94, line: 105]

  // Method descriptor #178 ([Ljava/net/URL;)V
  // Stack: 3, Locals: 2
  public URLClassPath(java.net.URL[] arg0);
    0  aload_0 [this]
    1  aload_1 [arg0]
    2  aconst_null
    3  invokespecial sun.misc.URLClassPath(java.net.URL[], java.net.URLStreamHandlerFactory) [319]
    6  return
      Line numbers:
        [pc: 0, line: 108]
        [pc: 6, line: 109]

  // Method descriptor #177 (Ljava/net/URL;)V
  // Stack: 3, Locals: 4
  public void addURL(java.net.URL arg0);
     0  aload_0 [this]
     1  getfield sun.misc.URLClassPath.urls : java.util.Stack [274]
     4  dup
     5  astore_2
     6  monitorenter
     7  aload_0 [this]
     8  getfield sun.misc.URLClassPath.path : java.util.ArrayList [272]
    11  aload_1 [arg0]
    12  invokevirtual java.util.ArrayList.contains(java.lang.Object) : boolean [302]
    15  ifeq 21
    18  aload_2
    19  monitorexit
    20  return
    21  aload_0 [this]
    22  getfield sun.misc.URLClassPath.urls : java.util.Stack [274]
    25  iconst_0
    26  aload_1 [arg0]
    27  invokevirtual java.util.Stack.add(int, java.lang.Object) : void [310]
    30  aload_0 [this]
    31  getfield sun.misc.URLClassPath.path : java.util.ArrayList [272]
    34  aload_1 [arg0]
    35  invokevirtual java.util.ArrayList.add(java.lang.Object) : boolean [301]
    38  pop
    39  aload_2
    40  monitorexit
    41  goto 49
    44  astore_3
    45  aload_2
    46  monitorexit
    47  aload_3
    48  athrow
    49  return
      Exception Table:
        [pc: 7, pc: 20] -> 44 when : any
        [pc: 21, pc: 41] -> 44 when : any
        [pc: 44, pc: 47] -> 44 when : any
      Line numbers:
        [pc: 0, line: 116]
        [pc: 7, line: 117]
        [pc: 18, line: 118]
        [pc: 21, line: 120]
        [pc: 30, line: 121]
        [pc: 39, line: 122]
        [pc: 49, line: 123]

  // Method descriptor #176 ()[Ljava/net/URL;
  // Stack: 2, Locals: 3
  public java.net.URL[] getURLs();
     0  aload_0 [this]
     1  getfield sun.misc.URLClassPath.urls : java.util.Stack [274]
     4  dup
     5  astore_1
     6  monitorenter
     7  aload_0 [this]
     8  getfield sun.misc.URLClassPath.path : java.util.ArrayList [272]
    11  aload_0 [this]
    12  getfield sun.misc.URLClassPath.path : java.util.ArrayList [272]
    15  invokevirtual java.util.ArrayList.size() : int [298]
    18  anewarray java.net.URL [144]
    21  invokevirtual java.util.ArrayList.toArray(java.lang.Object[]) : java.lang.Object[] [303]
    24  checkcast java.net.URL[] [130]
    27  checkcast java.net.URL[] [130]
    30  aload_1
    31  monitorexit
    32  areturn
    33  astore_2
    34  aload_1
    35  monitorexit
    36  aload_2
    37  athrow
      Exception Table:
        [pc: 7, pc: 32] -> 33 when : any
        [pc: 33, pc: 36] -> 33 when : any
      Line numbers:
        [pc: 0, line: 129]
        [pc: 7, line: 130]
        [pc: 33, line: 131]

  // Method descriptor #193 (Ljava/lang/String;Z)Ljava/net/URL;
  // Stack: 3, Locals: 6
  public java.net.URL findResource(java.lang.String arg0, boolean arg1);
     0  iconst_0
     1  istore 4
     3  aload_0 [this]
     4  iload 4
     6  invokespecial sun.misc.URLClassPath.getLoader(int) : sun.misc.URLClassPath$Loader [318]
     9  dup
    10  astore_3
    11  ifnull 36
    14  aload_3
    15  aload_1 [arg0]
    16  iload_2 [arg1]
    17  invokevirtual sun.misc.URLClassPath$Loader.findResource(java.lang.String, boolean) : java.net.URL [327]
    20  astore 5
    22  aload 5
    24  ifnull 30
    27  aload 5
    29  areturn
    30  iinc 4 1
    33  goto 3
    36  aconst_null
    37  areturn
      Line numbers:
        [pc: 0, line: 145]
        [pc: 14, line: 146]
        [pc: 22, line: 147]
        [pc: 27, line: 148]
        [pc: 30, line: 145]
        [pc: 36, line: 151]

  // Method descriptor #202 (Ljava/lang/String;Z)Lsun/misc/Resource;
  // Stack: 3, Locals: 6
  public sun.misc.Resource getResource(java.lang.String arg0, boolean arg1);
     0  getstatic sun.misc.URLClassPath.DEBUG : boolean [268]
     3  ifeq 36
     6  getstatic java.lang.System.err : java.io.PrintStream [267]
     9  new java.lang.StringBuilder [140]
    12  dup
    13  invokespecial java.lang.StringBuilder() [283]
    16  ldc <String "URLClassPath.getResource(""> [2]
    18  invokevirtual java.lang.StringBuilder.append(java.lang.String) : java.lang.StringBuilder [285]
    21  aload_1 [arg0]
    22  invokevirtual java.lang.StringBuilder.append(java.lang.String) : java.lang.StringBuilder [285]
    25  ldc <String "")"> [1]
    27  invokevirtual java.lang.StringBuilder.append(java.lang.String) : java.lang.StringBuilder [285]
    30  invokevirtual java.lang.StringBuilder.toString() : java.lang.String [284]
    33  invokevirtual java.io.PrintStream.println(java.lang.String) : void [277]
    36  iconst_0
    37  istore 4
    39  aload_0 [this]
    40  iload 4
    42  invokespecial sun.misc.URLClassPath.getLoader(int) : sun.misc.URLClassPath$Loader [318]
    45  dup
    46  astore_3
    47  ifnull 72
    50  aload_3
    51  aload_1 [arg0]
    52  iload_2 [arg1]
    53  invokevirtual sun.misc.URLClassPath$Loader.getResource(java.lang.String, boolean) : sun.misc.Resource [328]
    56  astore 5
    58  aload 5
    60  ifnull 66
    63  aload 5
    65  areturn
    66  iinc 4 1
    69  goto 39
    72  aconst_null
    73  areturn
      Line numbers:
        [pc: 0, line: 163]
        [pc: 6, line: 164]
        [pc: 36, line: 168]
        [pc: 50, line: 169]
        [pc: 58, line: 170]
        [pc: 63, line: 171]
        [pc: 66, line: 168]
        [pc: 72, line: 174]

  // Method descriptor #200 (Ljava/lang/String;Z)Ljava/util/Enumeration;
  // Stack: 5, Locals: 3
  public java.util.Enumeration findResources(java.lang.String arg0, boolean arg1);
     0  new sun.misc.URLClassPath$1 [155]
     3  dup
     4  aload_0 [this]
     5  aload_1 [arg0]
     6  iload_2 [arg1]
     7  invokespecial sun.misc.URLClassPath$1(sun.misc.URLClassPath, java.lang.String, boolean) [323]
    10  areturn
      Line numbers:
        [pc: 0, line: 186]

  // Method descriptor #201 (Ljava/lang/String;)Lsun/misc/Resource;
  // Stack: 3, Locals: 2
  public sun.misc.Resource getResource(java.lang.String arg0);
    0  aload_0 [this]
    1  aload_1 [arg0]
    2  iconst_1
    3  invokevirtual sun.misc.URLClassPath.getResource(java.lang.String, boolean) : sun.misc.Resource [321]
    6  areturn
      Line numbers:
        [pc: 0, line: 221]

  // Method descriptor #200 (Ljava/lang/String;Z)Ljava/util/Enumeration;
  // Stack: 5, Locals: 3
  public java.util.Enumeration getResources(java.lang.String arg0, boolean arg1);
     0  new sun.misc.URLClassPath$2 [156]
     3  dup
     4  aload_0 [this]
     5  aload_1 [arg0]
     6  iload_2 [arg1]
     7  invokespecial sun.misc.URLClassPath$2(sun.misc.URLClassPath, java.lang.String, boolean) [324]
    10  areturn
      Line numbers:
        [pc: 0, line: 233]

  // Method descriptor #199 (Ljava/lang/String;)Ljava/util/Enumeration;
  // Stack: 3, Locals: 2
  public java.util.Enumeration getResources(java.lang.String arg0);
    0  aload_0 [this]
    1  aload_1 [arg0]
    2  iconst_1
    3  invokevirtual sun.misc.URLClassPath.getResources(java.lang.String, boolean) : java.util.Enumeration [320]
    6  areturn
      Line numbers:
        [pc: 0, line: 268]

  // Method descriptor #182 (I)Lsun/misc/URLClassPath$Loader;
  // Stack: 3, Locals: 6
  private synchronized sun.misc.URLClassPath.Loader getLoader(int arg0);
      0  aload_0 [this]
      1  getfield sun.misc.URLClassPath.loaders : java.util.ArrayList [271]
      4  invokevirtual java.util.ArrayList.size() : int [298]
      7  iload_1 [arg0]
      8  iconst_1
      9  iadd
     10  if_icmpge 133
     13  aload_0 [this]
     14  getfield sun.misc.URLClassPath.urls : java.util.Stack [274]
     17  dup
     18  astore_3
     19  monitorenter
     20  aload_0 [this]
     21  getfield sun.misc.URLClassPath.urls : java.util.Stack [274]
     24  invokevirtual java.util.Stack.empty() : boolean [308]
     27  ifeq 34
     30  aconst_null
     31  aload_3
     32  monitorexit
     33  areturn
     34  aload_0 [this]
     35  getfield sun.misc.URLClassPath.urls : java.util.Stack [274]
     38  invokevirtual java.util.Stack.pop() : java.lang.Object [309]
     41  checkcast java.net.URL [144]
     44  astore_2
     45  aload_3
     46  monitorexit
     47  goto 57
     50  astore 4
     52  aload_3
     53  monitorexit
     54  aload 4
     56  athrow
     57  aload_2
     58  invokestatic sun.net.util.URLUtil.urlNoFragString(java.net.URL) : java.lang.String [329]
     61  astore_3
     62  aload_0 [this]
     63  getfield sun.misc.URLClassPath.lmap : java.util.HashMap [273]
     66  aload_3
     67  invokevirtual java.util.HashMap.containsKey(java.lang.Object) : boolean [305]
     70  ifeq 76
     73  goto 0
     76  aload_0 [this]
     77  aload_2
     78  invokespecial sun.misc.URLClassPath.getLoader(java.net.URL) : sun.misc.URLClassPath$Loader [322]
     81  astore 4
     83  aload 4
     85  invokevirtual sun.misc.URLClassPath$Loader.getClassPath() : java.net.URL[] [326]
     88  astore 5
     90  aload 5
     92  ifnull 101
     95  aload_0 [this]
     96  aload 5
     98  invokespecial sun.misc.URLClassPath.push(java.net.URL[]) : void [317]
    101  goto 109
    104  astore 5
    106  goto 0
    109  aload_0 [this]
    110  getfield sun.misc.URLClassPath.loaders : java.util.ArrayList [271]
    113  aload 4
    115  invokevirtual java.util.ArrayList.add(java.lang.Object) : boolean [301]
    118  pop
    119  aload_0 [this]
    120  getfield sun.misc.URLClassPath.lmap : java.util.HashMap [273]
    123  aload_3
    124  aload 4
    126  invokevirtual java.util.HashMap.put(java.lang.Object, java.lang.Object) : java.lang.Object [306]
    129  pop
    130  goto 0
    133  aload_0 [this]
    134  getfield sun.misc.URLClassPath.loaders : java.util.ArrayList [271]
    137  iload_1 [arg0]
    138  invokevirtual java.util.ArrayList.get(int) : java.lang.Object [300]
    141  checkcast sun.misc.URLClassPath$Loader [160]
    144  areturn
      Exception Table:
        [pc: 20, pc: 33] -> 50 when : any
        [pc: 34, pc: 47] -> 50 when : any
        [pc: 50, pc: 54] -> 50 when : any
        [pc: 76, pc: 101] -> 104 when : java.io.IOException
      Line numbers:
        [pc: 0, line: 279]
        [pc: 13, line: 282]
        [pc: 20, line: 283]
        [pc: 30, line: 284]
        [pc: 34, line: 286]
        [pc: 45, line: 288]
        [pc: 57, line: 292]
        [pc: 62, line: 293]
        [pc: 73, line: 294]
        [pc: 76, line: 299]
        [pc: 83, line: 302]
        [pc: 90, line: 303]
        [pc: 95, line: 304]
        [pc: 101, line: 309]
        [pc: 104, line: 306]
        [pc: 106, line: 308]
        [pc: 109, line: 311]
        [pc: 119, line: 312]
        [pc: 130, line: 313]
        [pc: 133, line: 314]

  // Method descriptor #203 (Ljava/net/URL;)Lsun/misc/URLClassPath$Loader;
  // Stack: 4, Locals: 3
  private sun.misc.URLClassPath.Loader getLoader(java.net.URL arg0) throws java.io.IOException;
     0  new sun.misc.URLClassPath$3 [157]
     3  dup
     4  aload_0 [this]
     5  aload_1 [arg0]
     6  invokespecial sun.misc.URLClassPath$3(sun.misc.URLClassPath, java.net.URL) [325]
     9  invokestatic java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(java.security.PrivilegedExceptionAction) : java.lang.Object [294]
    12  checkcast sun.misc.URLClassPath$Loader [160]
    15  areturn
    16  astore_2
    17  aload_2
    18  invokevirtual java.security.PrivilegedActionException.getException() : java.lang.Exception [297]
    21  checkcast java.io.IOException [133]
    24  athrow
      Exception Table:
        [pc: 0, pc: 15] -> 16 when : java.security.PrivilegedActionException
      Line numbers:
        [pc: 0, line: 322]
        [pc: 16, line: 337]
        [pc: 17, line: 338]

  // Method descriptor #178 ([Ljava/net/URL;)V
  // Stack: 3, Locals: 5
  private void push(java.net.URL[] arg0);
     0  aload_0 [this]
     1  getfield sun.misc.URLClassPath.urls : java.util.Stack [274]
     4  dup
     5  astore_2
     6  monitorenter
     7  aload_1 [arg0]
     8  arraylength
     9  iconst_1
    10  isub
    11  istore_3
    12  iload_3
    13  iflt 33
    16  aload_0 [this]
    17  getfield sun.misc.URLClassPath.urls : java.util.Stack [274]
    20  aload_1 [arg0]
    21  iload_3
    22  aaload
    23  invokevirtual java.util.Stack.push(java.lang.Object) : java.lang.Object [311]
    26  pop
    27  iinc 3 -1
    30  goto 12
    33  aload_2
    34  monitorexit
    35  goto 45
    38  astore 4
    40  aload_2
    41  monitorexit
    42  aload 4
    44  athrow
    45  return
      Exception Table:
        [pc: 7, pc: 35] -> 38 when : any
        [pc: 38, pc: 42] -> 38 when : any
      Line numbers:
        [pc: 0, line: 346]
        [pc: 7, line: 347]
        [pc: 16, line: 348]
        [pc: 27, line: 347]
        [pc: 33, line: 350]
        [pc: 45, line: 351]

  // Method descriptor #192 (Ljava/lang/String;)[Ljava/net/URL;
  // Stack: 5, Locals: 6
  public static java.net.URL[] pathToURLs(java.lang.String arg0);
      0  new java.util.StringTokenizer [153]
      3  dup
      4  aload_0 [arg0]
      5  getstatic java.io.File.pathSeparator : java.lang.String [266]
      8  invokespecial java.util.StringTokenizer(java.lang.String, java.lang.String) [315]
     11  astore_1
     12  aload_1
     13  invokevirtual java.util.StringTokenizer.countTokens() : int [312]
     16  anewarray java.net.URL [144]
     19  astore_2
     20  iconst_0
     21  istore_3
     22  aload_1
     23  invokevirtual java.util.StringTokenizer.hasMoreTokens() : boolean [313]
     26  ifeq 80
     29  new java.io.File [131]
     32  dup
     33  aload_1
     34  invokevirtual java.util.StringTokenizer.nextToken() : java.lang.String [314]
     37  invokespecial java.io.File(java.lang.String) [276]
     40  astore 4
     42  new java.io.File [131]
     45  dup
     46  aload 4
     48  invokevirtual java.io.File.getCanonicalPath() : java.lang.String [275]
     51  invokespecial java.io.File(java.lang.String) [276]
     54  astore 4
     56  goto 61
     59  astore 5
     61  aload_2
     62  iload_3
     63  iinc 3 1
     66  aload 4
     68  invokestatic sun.net.www.ParseUtil.fileToEncodedURL(java.io.File) : java.net.URL [330]
     71  aastore
     72  goto 77
     75  astore 5
     77  goto 22
     80  aload_2
     81  arraylength
     82  iload_3
     83  if_icmpeq 104
     86  iload_3
     87  anewarray java.net.URL [144]
     90  astore 4
     92  aload_2
     93  iconst_0
     94  aload 4
     96  iconst_0
     97  iload_3
     98  invokestatic java.lang.System.arraycopy(java.lang.Object, int, java.lang.Object, int, int) : void [287]
    101  aload 4
    103  astore_2
    104  aload_2
    105  areturn
      Exception Table:
        [pc: 42, pc: 56] -> 59 when : java.io.IOException
        [pc: 61, pc: 72] -> 75 when : java.io.IOException
      Line numbers:
        [pc: 0, line: 360]
        [pc: 12, line: 361]
        [pc: 20, line: 362]
        [pc: 22, line: 363]
        [pc: 29, line: 364]
        [pc: 42, line: 366]
        [pc: 56, line: 369]
        [pc: 59, line: 367]
        [pc: 61, line: 371]
        [pc: 72, line: 372]
        [pc: 77, line: 373]
        [pc: 80, line: 375]
        [pc: 86, line: 376]
        [pc: 92, line: 377]
        [pc: 101, line: 378]
        [pc: 104, line: 380]

  // Method descriptor #194 (Ljava/net/URL;)Ljava/net/URL;
  // Stack: 1, Locals: 3
  public java.net.URL checkURL(java.net.URL arg0);
     0  aload_1 [arg0]
     1  invokestatic sun.misc.URLClassPath.check(java.net.URL) : void [316]
     4  goto 10
     7  astore_2
     8  aconst_null
     9  areturn
    10  aload_1 [arg0]
    11  areturn
      Exception Table:
        [pc: 0, pc: 4] -> 7 when : java.lang.Exception
      Line numbers:
        [pc: 0, line: 390]
        [pc: 4, line: 393]
        [pc: 7, line: 391]
        [pc: 8, line: 392]
        [pc: 10, line: 395]

  // Method descriptor #177 (Ljava/net/URL;)V
  // Stack: 3, Locals: 6
  static void check(java.net.URL arg0) throws java.io.IOException;
      0  invokestatic java.lang.System.getSecurityManager() : java.lang.SecurityManager [286]
      3  astore_1
      4  aload_1
      5  ifnull 122
      8  aload_0 [arg0]
      9  invokevirtual java.net.URL.openConnection() : java.net.URLConnection [291]
     12  astore_2
     13  aload_2
     14  invokevirtual java.net.URLConnection.getPermission() : java.security.Permission [292]
     17  astore_3
     18  aload_3
     19  ifnull 122
     22  aload_1
     23  aload_3
     24  invokevirtual java.lang.SecurityManager.checkPermission(java.security.Permission) : void [281]
     27  goto 122
     30  astore 4
     32  aload_3
     33  instanceof java.io.FilePermission [132]
     36  ifeq 63
     39  aload_3
     40  invokevirtual java.security.Permission.getActions() : java.lang.String [295]
     43  ldc <String "read"> [6]
     45  invokevirtual java.lang.String.indexOf(java.lang.String) : int [282]
     48  iconst_m1
     49  if_icmpeq 63
     52  aload_1
     53  aload_3
     54  invokevirtual java.security.Permission.getName() : java.lang.String [296]
     57  invokevirtual java.lang.SecurityManager.checkRead(java.lang.String) : void [279]
     60  goto 122
     63  aload_3
     64  instanceof java.net.SocketPermission [143]
     67  ifeq 119
     70  aload_3
     71  invokevirtual java.security.Permission.getActions() : java.lang.String [295]
     74  ldc <String "connect"> [3]
     76  invokevirtual java.lang.String.indexOf(java.lang.String) : int [282]
     79  iconst_m1
     80  if_icmpeq 119
     83  aload_0 [arg0]
     84  astore 5
     86  aload_2
     87  instanceof java.net.JarURLConnection [142]
     90  ifeq 102
     93  aload_2
     94  checkcast java.net.JarURLConnection [142]
     97  invokevirtual java.net.JarURLConnection.getJarFileURL() : java.net.URL [288]
    100  astore 5
    102  aload_1
    103  aload 5
    105  invokevirtual java.net.URL.getHost() : java.lang.String [290]
    108  aload 5
    110  invokevirtual java.net.URL.getPort() : int [289]
    113  invokevirtual java.lang.SecurityManager.checkConnect(java.lang.String, int) : void [280]
    116  goto 122
    119  aload 4
    121  athrow
    122  return
      Exception Table:
        [pc: 22, pc: 27] -> 30 when : java.lang.SecurityException
      Line numbers:
        [pc: 0, line: 404]
        [pc: 4, line: 405]
        [pc: 8, line: 406]
        [pc: 13, line: 407]
        [pc: 18, line: 408]
        [pc: 22, line: 410]
        [pc: 27, line: 429]
        [pc: 30, line: 411]
        [pc: 32, line: 414]
        [pc: 52, line: 416]
        [pc: 63, line: 417]
        [pc: 83, line: 420]
        [pc: 86, line: 421]
        [pc: 93, line: 422]
        [pc: 102, line: 424]
        [pc: 116, line: 426]
        [pc: 119, line: 427]
        [pc: 122, line: 432]

  // Method descriptor #204 (Lsun/misc/URLClassPath;I)Lsun/misc/URLClassPath$Loader;
  // Stack: 2, Locals: 2
  static synthetic sun.misc.URLClassPath.Loader access$000(sun.misc.URLClassPath arg0, int arg1);
    0  aload_0 [arg0]
    1  iload_1 [arg1]
    2  invokespecial sun.misc.URLClassPath.getLoader(int) : sun.misc.URLClassPath$Loader [318]
    5  areturn
      Line numbers:
        [pc: 0, line: 60]

  // Method descriptor #197 (Lsun/misc/URLClassPath;)Ljava/net/URLStreamHandler;
  // Stack: 1, Locals: 1
  static synthetic java.net.URLStreamHandler access$100(sun.misc.URLClassPath arg0);
    0  aload_0 [arg0]
    1  getfield sun.misc.URLClassPath.jarHandler : java.net.URLStreamHandler [270]
    4  areturn
      Line numbers:
        [pc: 0, line: 60]

  // Method descriptor #12 ()Z
  // Stack: 1, Locals: 0
  static synthetic boolean access$300();
    0  getstatic sun.misc.URLClassPath.DEBUG : boolean [268]
    3  ireturn
      Line numbers:
        [pc: 0, line: 60]

  // Method descriptor #11 ()V
  // Stack: 3, Locals: 0
  static {};
     0  new sun.security.action.GetPropertyAction [163]
     3  dup
     4  ldc <String "java.version"> [5]
     6  invokespecial sun.security.action.GetPropertyAction(java.lang.String) [331]
     9  invokestatic java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(java.security.PrivilegedAction) : java.lang.Object [293]
    12  checkcast java.lang.String [139]
    15  putstatic sun.misc.URLClassPath.JAVA_VERSION : java.lang.String [269]
    18  new sun.security.action.GetPropertyAction [163]
    21  dup
    22  ldc <String "sun.misc.URLClassPath.debug"> [7]
    24  invokespecial sun.security.action.GetPropertyAction(java.lang.String) [331]
    27  invokestatic java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(java.security.PrivilegedAction) : java.lang.Object [293]
    30  ifnull 37
    33  iconst_1
    34  goto 38
    37  iconst_0
    38  putstatic sun.misc.URLClassPath.DEBUG : boolean [268]
    41  return
      Line numbers:
        [pc: 0, line: 66]
        [pc: 18, line: 68]
        [pc: 41, line: 70]

  Inner classes:
    [inner class info: #155 sun/misc/URLClassPath$1, outer class info: #0
     inner name: #0, accessflags: 0 default],
    [inner class info: #156 sun/misc/URLClassPath$2, outer class info: #0
     inner name: #0, accessflags: 0 default],
    [inner class info: #157 sun/misc/URLClassPath$3, outer class info: #0
     inner name: #0, accessflags: 0 default],
    [inner class info: #158 sun/misc/URLClassPath$FileLoader, outer class info: #154 sun/misc/URLClassPath
     inner name: #333 FileLoader, accessflags: 10 private static],
    [inner class info: #159 sun/misc/URLClassPath$JarLoader, outer class info: #154 sun/misc/URLClassPath
     inner name: #334 JarLoader, accessflags: 8 static],
    [inner class info: #160 sun/misc/URLClassPath$Loader, outer class info: #154 sun/misc/URLClassPath
     inner name: #335 Loader, accessflags: 10 private static]
}
```

I thought it may be an issue between the compiler and the JDK. I have attempted adjusting settings, but nothing has resolved the issue as of now. Please let me know if I need to supply more information.

Comment: Not sure why you've posted the compiled version of URLClassPath. Which development environment are you using?

Answer (score 0):

When targeting GWT, you need to take extra care to *not* access or mention classes for which you don't have the source code ready in a GWT module. This is due to the way that GWT works - it compiles to Javascript not class files, but Java source code - and it also does whole program optimization, meaning that *all* classes that may be used in your program will be compiled into JS (also meaning that dynamic class loading isn't possible).

What you show here is the disassembly of the classfile corresponding to `sun.misc.URLClassPath`, and it is about as useful to a GWT program as a bicycle to a fish. First, GWT does not have the concept of a ClassPath, given that all the code used in a GWT module is known to the compiler. Secondly, it's in the `sun.misc` package, for which you almost certainly don't have the source code.

Given the last point the error message is understandable, this reference however indicates that you either misunderstand GWT ind a deep level, or that you copied code from f.e. an applet.

To resolve this error, do not reference that class.

Comment: The list of classes that you can use in your client code is to be found on the [JRE Emulation Reference page](http://code.google.com/webtoolkit/doc/latest/RefJreEmulation.html).

Comment: This is completely understandable, but to my knowledge there is no reference to the class in my code. The code is copied directly from the Google tutorial and I have looked it over attempting to find the issue. I went back to plain Eclipse (I was using the spring framework) and it worked properly there.

Comment: @Lars: When you debug it in Eclipse, the Development Mode view will show you the error. Increase the log level of the hosted mode launcher to view the class stack used when it hits this class.

Answer (score 0):

You have double GWT jars into your eclipse classpath.